# Semantic rules in compiler

Tags: compiler-construction

I am confused about the semantic rules which is used during syntax directed definition (SDD) and syntax directed translation (SDT).

How do we get the semantic rules? Is it like the grammar that needs to be specified by the developer for the language.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in order for you not to be confused, you have to take things from the start.

You already know, that in order to specify a language, at the lexical and at the syntactic level, you have to different constructs, and those are `tokens` (implemented mostly by regular expressions), which specify the lexical structure of some code, and the `(context free) grammar`, which specifies the structure of some code at the syntactic level (providing later phases of the compiler with a easier to handle representation - the `abstract syntax tree` - while doing syntactic sanity checkings itself, i.e making sure that the input is valid and not syntactically malformed).

For instance, assuming you have the following small code snippet:

```
int c = a + 5;
```

Then by the end of the lexical analysis, you have the following tokens (let's assume there are actual token definitions that look like them in your language's spec, but let's keep it simple for now):

```
INT(int)
IDENTIFIER(c)
OPERATOR(=)
IDENTIFIER(a)
OPERATOR(+)
NUMBER(5)
STATEMENT_TERMINATOR
```

which are then passed on to the parser, who creates the following syntax tree:

```
     =
    / \
   /   \
  c     +
       / \
      a   5
```

By now though, you have recognized that this language construct is valid and well formed, but you have done nothing to derive its meaning. What does the `+` operator represent? What does `a` represent? What does `=` represent (as an action)? Is the operation semantically valid (i.e you are not adding a character and a number)?

For this reason, you need to also specify the `semantic rules` for a language.

It is at this point that we arrive at the `Syntax Directed Definition` (also known as `Attribute Grammar`). A `Syntax Directed Definition` is the `Context-Free Grammar` that we used earlier to do our parsing (why invent a new notation, when we have a very good one already to do our job), *but* augmented with `attributes` attached to the `grammar symbols`, and `semantic rules` attached to the productions.

For instance, the Context Free Grammar of the language that contains our code above might have as production rules:

```
E --> E1 + T
E --> <identifier>
T --> <number>
```

In this case, our syntax directed definition (using synthesized attributed) would be this:

```
E --> E1 + T       { E.val = E1.val + T.val; }
E --> <identifier> { E.val = identifier.val; }
T --> <number>     { T.val = number.val; }
```

which says that the final expression would get its value by adding the value of the first expression, along with the value of the term on the right of the plus operator, along with specifying rules on how to get the value of an identifier expression and a term factor.

Comment: is this synthesized attributes created by the compiler during the process?